# Check Password change to ensure that new password doesn't equal last password used

Tags: c#, razor, webmatrix, change-password

I was just wondering how I could check (when a user is changing password after the password expires) how I could use (in WebMatrix) an if branch to ensure that the new password does not equal the previous password.

I don't think I want to check for any more password history beyond just the last password used, so as long as I can just check the previous password, I think that will be fine.

I could of course query the database and check, but as the password doesn't get stored in plain text, I know that this won't work, but I also checked on the WebSecurity methods here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity(v=vs.111).aspx

and didn't find anything.

What is the best way to get this done?

Comment: @everyone, I like how I always try to start my posts with "Hello, everyone" and it always omits the "Hello" part (deliberately, I'm sure) so it just sounds like I am addressing the community with a Stalin-like tone, lol :)

Comment: It's pretty much due to a couple of factors you can read about on [meta.stackoverflow.com - Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989)

Comment: @Erik Philips Oh, that's okay, I'm sure there's a good reason, I'm not complaining. I just thought it was funny, and wanted to explain to anyone reading this, that I am not trying to be rude. :) Thanks for the link, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the password is not stored in the database, there is no way for you to do this, unless you make a note of the password when the user first registers, and whenever they subsequently change it.

The irony here is that by storing the original password (even in an encrypted state), you actually reduce the security of your application.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I was afraid of.  I really don't want to compromise security with this application, given the nature of it's potential future environment.  How do other sites accomplish this?  I mean I know I have seen some sites do this (probably not with Web Pages though).  Anyway, thanks for the answer, Mike

Comment: Is there no way to force C# to check the password in the encrypted form that it's in? I mean, like when a user logs in, for instance. I know the code has to check against this password in some way in order to authenticate the user. Is there no way to force C# to check against the user's password in much the same way that it does when a user attempts to log in?

Comment: Also, I saw a "SimpleMembershipProvider.GetPassword" method listed here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider.getpassword(v=vs.111).aspx ----- But, I couldn't get anything to work with it (honestly, I don't think I understand how, where, and/or when this method is supposed to be used).

Comment: Also, I'm not totally sure what you mean when you say, "Since the password is not stored in the database." I mean, it is stored in a database, just in an encrypted form.  Is that what you meant, not stored (unencrypted) in the database, or is my question confusing?

Comment: The password itself is not stored in the database. A hash is stored there instead. The hash is generated in such a way as to make decryption nigh on impossible. You can read more on the details here: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/200/The-SimpleMembershipProvider-Secure-Passwords-And-The-Crypto-Helper. I don't understand why you are concerned that people don't reset a password to the same as it was. Most other sites allow this. The GetPassword method is not implemented in the SimpleMembership Provider.

Comment: Well, I pretty much get instructions to do something (by non-IT administrators), and then I give my advise, and sometimes they say, "do it anyway" so, I just do it. I am to let the password expire after 6 months, then they are forced to change their password.  If I let them always repeat the same password, with these guys, I may as well just not do it at all, because they will repeat it... over and over and over... I just know them, lol

Comment: If you care to check out the workaround I came up with just read the answer I posted below.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For any who are interested, I did find a nice workaround to this question, that gets the job done just fine.

Keep in mind, though, that this will only work to check the very last password they had/have.

This is what I implemented:

First, of course, in the log-in page, among other code and after actual log-in, I have the obvious (to check if their password is over 6 months old and require change):

```
if(WebSecurity.GetPasswordChangedDate(username).AddMonths(6) < DateTime.UtcNow)
{
    WebSecurity.Logout();
    Session["gActionMessage"] = "Your password has expired. Please change your password by visiting \"Login\" then \"Change Password\"";
    Session["gActionMessageDisplayed"] = "not";
    Response.Redirect("~/");
}
```

Then, I came up with this on the "Change Password" page (actually the redirected page after email verification for password reset token, but you get the idea):

```
if(WebSecurity.Login(email, newPassword, false) && WebSecurity.UserExists(email) && WebSecurity.GetPasswordChangedDate(email).AddMonths(6) < DateTime.UtcNow)
{
    WebSecurity.Logout();
    errorMessage = "You cannot repeat your last expired password.";
}
```

The if branch here does three checks:

First, it effectively checks and logs them in if possible based off of what they typed in as their new password.

Secondly, it checks if the user exists (not really sure if I even need this, but whatever).

And lastly, checks to make sure that their password change date is over 6 months old (because the same page is used for "forgot password" stuff, so this just ensures that the right circumstances are met before erring in this way).

So, in short, if their new password is still sufficient to log them in (before it actually gets changed, of course), then it is a repeat and subsequently logs them out and throws the error message at them instead of changing the password.  If it is not sufficient to log them in, then it can't be a repeated password, and (so long as it meets any other requirements) the password is then changed.

Hope this helps anyone, who may require a non-repeated password using WebMatrix upon password change, in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Reference the System.Web.Helpers assembly,

Create a custom table called 'UserPasswordHistory' that contains stored hashed passwords in the 'Password' column with an incremented version number in the 'PasswordVersion' column, a row of which is inserted each time a user is registered or a password updated for a given user,
the following code works.

```
var userProfile = db.UserProfiles.First(x => x.UserId == userId);
                var passwords = (userProfile.UserPasswordHistory
                                          .OrderByDescending(x => x.PasswordVersion)
                                          .Take(_configuration.PasswordCountBeforeReuseAllowed))
                                          .Select(x => x.Password);

return passwords.Any(previousPassword => Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(previousPassword, password));
```

To answer the question specifically asked  _configuration.PasswordCountBeforeReuseAllowed would be set to 1